# Database operations are not executed after the creation of document in my mongodb datasase

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to run the following code on my Mac machine (python 3.8), but the ids are not printed. It seems that the interpreter does not reach that part of the code at all.

```
import pymongo

myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "mongodb://localhost:27017")

mydb = myclient["mydatebase"]
mycol = mydb["customers"]

mylist = [
  { "name": "Amy", "address": "Apple st 652"},
  { "name": "Hannah", "address": "Mountain 21"},
  { "name": "Michael", "address": "Valley 345"},
  { "name": "Sandy", "address": "Ocean blvd 2"},
  { "name": "Betty", "address": "Green Grass 1"},
  { "name": "Richard", "address": "Sky st 331"},
  { "name": "Susan", "address": "One way 98"},
  { "name": "Vicky", "address": "Yellow Garden 2"},
  { "name": "Ben", "address": "Park Lane 38"},
  { "name": "William", "address": "Central st 954"},
  { "name": "Chuck", "address": "Main Road 989"},
  { "name": "Viola", "address": "Sideway 1633"}
]

x = mycol.insert_many(mylist)

print(x.inserted_ids)
```

It seems that `myclient` is created without any problem, as I get `"successful"` when I run:

```
try:
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(
        "mongodb://localhost:27017")
    print("successful")
except:
    print("Unsucessful")
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: there is a spacing in the opening brace for each of your individual array item. can you remove that and try again? `insertMany` will only execute at strictly formatted JSON objects.

Comment: @kenmistry: Removing those spurious spaces changed nothing.

Comment: can you run the following on `mongo`? `use mydatebase` and `db.customers.find()`. what is the output?

Comment: @kenmistry: I reinstalled my mongodb, and the problem just got resolved. Thanks, anyway.